# how do i get only the time in python without the date and year?

Tags: python, time

I need to get time in python and i am using `time.ctime()` and it returns this Thu Jul  8 15:37:26 2021

But i only need 15:37:26 and i cant figure out how to get only this and not the date and year.

I already tried using datetime where i could not figure it out either so im trying with time now.

here is a bit of code for the context:

```
cas = time.ctime()
cas = str(cas)
api.update_status('nyni je:'+ cas )
time.sleep(60)
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   import datetime
   print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html for more info

Comment: yeah that works but how do i get rid of the decimal in 15:51:41.080578 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
print(datetime.datetime.now().time().isoformat(timespec='seconds'))
```

Answer (score 0):

imports

```
from datetime import datetime
```

code

```
now = datetime.now()
cas = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

print(cas)
```

You can use strftime to convert a datetime value to a string of a certain format. In your case you can use %H:%M:%S to only get the time. The same function can be used to get the date as well, you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date).
Take a look at the "strftime() and strptime() Format Codes" section also for how you can format it.